# Block matrix reduce system for finite element method

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices, gaussian-elimination

To solve a problem using the finite element method, we make a big matrix "connecting" many small matrix, each is computed using one element, like

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\square & \square & & & \\
\square & \square+\circ & \circ & & \\
& \circ & \circ + \triangleleft & \triangleleft & \\
& & \triangleleft & \triangleleft + \lozenge & \lozenge \\
& & & \lozenge & \lozenge \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[K_{exp}\right]} = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\square & \square & & & \\
\square & \square & & & \\
& & & & \\
& & & & \\
& & & & \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[A\right]} + 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
& & & & \\
& \circ & \circ & & \\
& \circ & \circ & & \\
& & & & \\
& & & & \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[B\right]}
+ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
& & & & \\
& & & & \\
& & \triangleleft & \triangleleft & \\
& & \triangleleft & \triangleleft & \\
& &   &   & \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[C\right]}
+ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
& & & & \\
& & & & \\
& &   &   & \\
& & & \lozenge & \lozenge \\
& & & \lozenge & \lozenge \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[D\right]}
$$

And then solve the system

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[A_{11}\right] & \left[A_{12}\right] & \left[0\right]  & \left[0\right] & \left[0\right] \\
\left[A_{12}^{T}\right] & \left[A_{22}\right] + \left[B_{11}\right] & \left[B_{12}\right] & \left[0\right]  & \left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[B_{12}^{T}\right] & \left[B_{22}\right] + \left[C_{11}\right] & \left[C_{12}\right] & \left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] & \left[C_{12}^{T}\right] & \left[C_{22}\right] + \left[D_{11}\right] & \left[D_{12}\right]  \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] & \left[0\right] & \left[D_{12}^{T}\right] & \left[D_{22}\right]  \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[K_{exp}\right]}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[U_{1}\right] \\ \left[U_{2}\right] \\ \left[U_{3}\right] \\ \left[U_{4}\right] \\ \left[U_{5}\right]
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[U_{exp}\right]} =
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[F_{1}\right] \\ \left[F_{2}\right] \\ \left[F_{3}\right] \\ \left[F_{4}\right] \\ \left[F_{5}\right]
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[F_{exp}\right]}
$$

Then, I want to "exclude" nodes and reduce the matrix. That means, transform the matrix $\left[M\right]$

$$
\left[M\right] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[M_{11}\right] &\left[M_{12}\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[M_{12}^T\right] &\left[M_{22}\right] &\left[M_{23}\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[M_{23}^T\right] &\left[M_{33}\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right]
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[B_{11}\right] &\left[B_{12}\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[B_{12}^T\right] & \left[B_{22}\right] + \left[C_{11}\right] &\left[C_{12}\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[C_{12}^T\right] &\left[C_{22}\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right]
\end{bmatrix}
$$

into a new matrix $\left[W\right]$

$$
\left[W\right] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[0\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[W_{11}\right] &\left[W_{12}\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[W_{12}^T\right] &\left[W_{22}\right] &\left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] &\left[0\right]  &\left[0\right]
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Such that the system bellow (with $K_{red}$) has the same solution for $\left[U_{1}\right], \ \left[U_{2}\right], \ \left[U_{4}\right]$ and $\left[U_{5}\right]$ as the frist system (with $K_{exp}$).

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[A_{11}\right] & \left[A_{12}\right] & \left[0\right] & \left[0\right] \\
\left[A_{12}^{T}\right] & \left[A_{22}\right] + \left[W_{11}\right] & \left[W_{12}\right] & \left[0\right] \\
\left[0\right] &  \left[W_{12}^{T}\right] & \left[W_{22}\right] + \left[D_{11}\right] & \left[D_{12}\right] \\
\left[0\right] & \left[0\right] & \left[D_{12}^{T}\right] & \left[D_{22}\right] \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[K_{red}\right]} \cdot 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[U_{1}\right] \\ \left[U_{2}\right] \\ \left[U_{4}\right] \\ \left[U_{5}\right]
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[U_{red}\right]} =
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[F_{1}\right] \\ \left[F_{2}\right] \\ \left[F_{4}\right] \\ \left[F_{5}\right]
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[F_{red}\right]} + 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[0\right] \\
\left[Z_{1}\right]  \\
\left[Z_{2}\right]  \\
\left[0\right] 
\end{bmatrix}}_{\left[Z\right]}
\left[F_{3}\right]
$$

**Question:** How can I get the reduced the matrix $\left[W\right]$ from the matrix $\left[M\right]$?

**My attempt:**

> Frist I will take out the block matrix notation.
> Our equations are
>
> $$
> \begin{bmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12} &  \\
> M_{12}^{T} & M_{22} & M_{23} \\
> & M_{23}^{T}  & M_{33} 
> \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} U_{2} \\ U_{3} \\ U_{4}  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}F_{2} \\ F_{3} \\ F_{4}  \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> We can write $\left[U_{3}\right]$ as
>
> $$
> \left[U_{3}\right] = \left[M_{22}\right]^{-1} \left( \left[F_{2}\right] -  \left[M_{12}^{T}\right]\left[U_{2}\right] -  \left[M_{23}\right]\left[U_{4}\right] \right)
> $$
> Therefore, applying in the equations we get
>
> $$ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
> (M_{11} - M_{12} M_{22}^{-1}M_{12}^{T}) & -M_{12}M_{22}^{-1}M_{23} \\
> -M_{23}^{T} M_{22}^{-1}M_{12}^{T} & (M_{33} - M_{23}^{T}M_{22}^{-1}M_{23})
> \end{bmatrix} }_{W}
> \begin{bmatrix} U_{2} \\ U_{4} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F_{2} \\ F_{4} \end{bmatrix}+  
> \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} -M_{12} \\ -M_{23}^{T} \end{bmatrix} M_{22}^{-1}}_{Z} F_{3}$$
>
> But it seems wrong to me. I don't know if I can sum this $W$ into the main matrix.
>
> **EDIT:** I created an algorithm ([link of GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/carlos-adir/a446a44828451b121ebf4fd7eddfdf21)) to create random symmetric matrix and compare the $U_{exp}$ solution to $U_{red}$ solution when $F_3 = 0$. Within a certain tolerance, they are equal. But I don't know if it's due the numerical error or about the theory.

**PS:** I'm working in a static mechanical problem, where the forces and boundary conditions are only applied on the boundary. The only force in internal nodes would be the field (like gravity). So I could "exclude" the interior nodes, these which the applied force $\left[F_{3}\right]$ is always constant, and everytime I re-run the simulation, I don't need to compute the interior nodes again.